# Efficiently selecting rows from pandas dataframe using sorted column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large-ish pandas dataframe with multiple columns (c1 ... c8) and ~32 mil rows. The dataframe is already sorted by c1. I want to grab other column values from rows that share a particular value of c1.

something like

```
keys = big_df['c1'].unique()
red = np.zeros(len(keys))
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    inds = (big_df['c1'] == key)
    v1 = np.array(big_df.loc[inds]['c2'])
    v2 = np.array(big_df.loc[inds]['c6'])
    red[i] = reduce_fun(v1,v2)
```

However this turns out to be very slow I think because it checks the entire columns for the matching criterion (even though there might only be 10 rows out of 32 mil that are relevant). Since big_df is sorted by c1 and the keys is just the list of all unique c1's, is there a fast way to get the red[] array (ie i know the first row with the next key is the row after the last row of the previous key, I know that the last row for a key is the last row that matches the key, since all subsequent rows are guaranteed not to match).

Thanks,

Ilya

Edit: I am not sure what order unique() method produces, but I basically want to have for every key in keys a value of reduce_fun(), I don't particularly care what order they are (presumably the easiest order is the order c1 is already sorted in).

Edit2: I slightly restructured the code. Basically, is there an efficient way of constructing inds. big_df['c1'] == key takes 75.8% of total time in my data, while creating v1, v2 takes 21.6% according to line profiler.

Comment: Pandas does not provide indexed row access in the database meaning of the term. Sequential access is the only option, I am afraid - unless you convert the dataframe to an array or list of lists and do search yourself. But then the conversion operation will take as much time as the original selection itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a list, I chose a dictionary to hold the reduced values keyed on each item in `c1`.

```
red = {key: reduce_func(frame['c2'].values, frame['c7'].values) 
       for key, frame in df.groupby('c1')}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a `groupby` statement in a list comprehension?  This should be especially efficient given the `DataFrame` is already sorted by `c1`:

**Edit**:  Forgot that `groupby` returns a tuple.  Oops!

```
red = [reduce_fun(g['c2'].values, g['c6'].values) for i, g in big_df.groupby('c1', sort=False)]
```

Seems to chug through pretty quickly for me (~2 seconds for 30 million random rows and a trivial reduce_fun).

Comment: This seems to work with minor correction that df.groupby returns a tuple (key, df) so it has to be g[1]['c2'], etc. Running timing test now.